# Does the precondition contains all possible necessary preconditions or not?

Tags: java

> Does the precondition contains all possible necessary preconditions or not?

I have to solve an exercise for university. The extended question is wether one has to make sure in an assert in the precondition that a the input will not cause an OutOfBoundsException or does one have to catch the out of bounds exception manually inside the function? SIZE is the lenght of the array.

Code 1:

```
  public boolean[][] driveForward(int moves){
    assert(0<= x + orientation.xForward(moves) && x + orientation.xForward(moves) <SIZE && 0 <= y + orientation.yForward(moves) && y + orientation.yForward(moves)<SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i <= moves; i++) {
        trail[x + orientation.xForward(i)][y + orientation.yForward(i)] = true;
```

Code 2:

```
   public boolean[][] driveForward(int moves){
    assert(0<=moves && moves<SIZE);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= moves; i++) {
            trail[x + orientation.xForward(i)][y + orientation.yForward(i)] = true;
        }
        assert invariant();

    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("this move is not allowed, you are out of the boarder");
    }
```

Comment: What do you think? What's your reasoning and why are you not confident with your reasoning?

Comment: Because I'm having a fight with my team college. I think one should combine these two things and I think yes the precondition should include everything such that the error can be found rapidly

Comment: `assert invariant();` should also be called at the start of every for-loop step in Code 2. (That is the reason there are invariants.) Similar in Code 1.

Comment: ok but what is now the answer what should i do?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant language tags. In general, a question should have only one language tag at most.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one semms to know an anwser to this questio I'm going to answer it by myself. No the precondition doesn't have to contain all possible preconditions it is a matter of choice. Both Code 1 and Code 2 are correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).